# Correlation between spatial distributions

Tags: distributions, correlation, spatial, cross-correlation

I have three bivariate data sets of different sizes and the same sampling interval. These represent  the variation of dry river bed direction with distance at equidistant sample points. When plotted there are clear similarities between  the datasets, the bends and their change in direction occur in the same order and magnitude, but some are delayed. I need to prove their equivalence in shape, I have considered co variance but what degree of matching can be demonstrated ? or  I could correlate (?)  data across the data sets to show equivalence but how to handle the differences in sample number and feature delay? I would appreciate some guidance please.

[image: Graphic Representation of the three data sets showing the similarities in envelope]

Comment: Do you have a single observation for each distribution?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the distributions were determined from satellite images using manually plotted polygons and lines within ARCGIS.

Comment: Do you have three observations of the distribution of one single spatial process, a single observation for the respective distribution of three spatial processes, or many observations for the distribution of three spatial processes? Could you clarify with some notations, like... Let $t$ denote a spatial index. Let $F_i(x(t))$ be the distribution of a spatial stochastic process $x$ at location $t$ measured at time $i$.

Comment: So you have a sample of observed distributions $F_x$, $F_y$ and $F_y$ for the three processes $x$, $y$ and $z$? Is the object of interest the covariance between those distributions?

Comment: I have three river channels of different lengths, which have  the same features of  bends, flow direction etc. in approx. the same locations (relatively).  I want to demonstrate these channels are very similar with a measure of confidence for that assertion. Each channel centreline profile = F(distance, channel direction).  Time = const -> erosion has ceased. I could scale the channels to make them visually match but this lacks rigour. I want to use a method that is readily understood by post grad level people who are not necessarily experts in  statistics ( this includes myself)

Comment: I am assuming that the three channels have been subject to the same processes which have yielded three similar channel profiles Fx, Fy and Fz. Whilst I could compare the covariance of each profile this does not really demonstrate their shapes are the same in detail(?)

Comment: I'm unsure what are channel profiles. If those are probability distributions of the spatial processes, and you have several measurements for each of those distributions, then the covariance operator could provide valuable insights. Otherwise I have no clue what you're asking for. Could you post some figures with the channel profiles?

Comment: A channel profile comprises discrete equidistant points along the channel central axis and these are associated with the direction of the channel axis at each point. This characterises the way the channel bends along its length.

Comment: Each of the three different length rivers has a sequence of bends along their lengths. The sequence of bends for each river are very similar but differ in detail at some locations, and there are variations in size and length but the shapes match. I was considering co variance but I do not appreciate what level of detail in shape matching can be claimed by using this method, and how the level of matching would be demonstrated.  As the rivers are of different lengths but the sampling interval for each is the same, the data quantity for each river is different.

Comment: Can you post your data, and maybe a plot? I still can't understand your situation.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, maybe you could try some sequence alignment method? Like dynamic time warping or its multidimensional version?

Comment: @dv_bn , and hung I have prepared a representation of the data for posting which could help -- its pdf, I am new to the site and not sure how or where to do it

Comment: Post it as an image? @gung probably knows better.

Comment: You can't post a pdf. Make a figure & save it as a png file on your machine. You can upload a png into your question.

Comment: I've added a representation of the data, there are some issues preventing publishing the actual data, any clarifications please contact me. The ordinates and abscissa have the same incremental intervals.

Comment: So this is your full data set right? Start by rescaling by relative distance so that you can superpose them.

Comment: In fact, you just need to align them correctly to see how their shapes coincide... I still don't see the statistical challenge here...

Comment: I have already normalised the plots and centred them on the maximum value which has enabled me to effectively stretch / shrink the axis either side since they have a degree of asymmetry . The outline plots I provided have not included many of the low level perturbations which are imposed on them. While the similarities of the plot are relatively obvious what I was looking for was a test / a quantification of how good the matches between them really are. The problem is testing how the envelopes match and maybe dynamic time warping is a better option. Anyway , thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I used DTW with considerable success (the dtw Cran package). As I had only 6 distributions  extra effort was required to generate randomised test profiles similar to the subject profiles to select the most appropriate settings and step pattern for the DTW algorithm.